# How to handle event in Opencart?

Tags: php, opencart, opencart2.x, opencart2.3, opencart-events

I cant understand Opencart event system. For example, I want to push order to external CRM, which have own API. I wrote in file */admin/controller/extension/module/mykmykpet_bitrix24.php* next code:

```
class ControllerExtensionModuleMykmykpetBitrix24 extends Controller{
    public function install(){
        $this->load->model('extension/event');
        $this->model_extension_event->addEvent('Bitrix24','catalog/model/checkout/order/addOrder/after','extension/module/mykmykpet_bitrix24/newOrderToCRM');
    }

    public function uninstall(){
        $this->load->model('extension/event');
        $this->model_extension_event->deleteEvent('Bitrix24');
    }
}
```

Next, for training I wrote in */catalog/controller/extension/module/mykmykpet_bitrix24.php* next code:

```
class ControllerExtensionModuleMykmykpetBitrix24 extends Controller{
    public function newOrderToCRM($orderID){
        mail("mykmykpet@mykmykpet.xyz","Hello from OpenCart Event",$orderID);
    }    
}
```

Next, I place test order and got this e-mail:
[E-mail content](https://i.stack.imgur.com/flbTh.png)

But why I got that? I wait an order identificator, but not path to method I used. Where is my mistake? Help me, please.

Answer (score 0):

You will have to look in `$this->request` for order_id, but I'm sure it will be in there somewhere.  It won't be passed as a parameter by the event system.

Answer (score 0):

**OpenCart 2.3.0.2**

In your example `order_id` is in the third parameter. you can test it with your log:

```
public function newOrderToCRM($route = false, $order_info = false, $order_id = false){
    $this->log->write('Route: ' . $route);
    $this->log->write('Order Info: ');
    $this->log->write($order_info);
    $this->log->write('Order ID: ' . $order_id);
}
```

Place an order and then check your error log, This is the result for me:

> 2018-01-05 17:04:17 - Route: checkout/order/addOrder
>
> 2018-01-05 17:04:17 - Order Info: 2018-01-05 17:04:17 - Array(Order information inside array)
>
> 2018-01-05 17:04:17 - Order ID: 130